# Select records with no releations

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming I have 3 tables:

```
People
-------------
PID   |  NAME
-------------
1       Bob
2       Garry
3       Alex
4       Peter
5       Victor

Tasks
-------------
TID   |  TASK
-------------
1       Work
2       Work Hard
3       Work Harder
```

And table that assigns tasks to people

```
Assigns
-------------
PID   |  TID
-------------
1       2
2       1
4       3
```

Question:
How do I select People who were not assigned to any task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` approach will work, but here are two more approaches that you might find easier to read:

**1. NOT IN**

```
SELECT NAME
FROM People
WHERE PID NOT IN
(
    SELECT PID
    FROM Assigns
)
```

**2. NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT NAME
FROM People
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Assigns
    WHERE People.PID = Assigns.PID
)
```

**Result**

```
Alex
Victor
```

**Related**

- [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: Oracle](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)

Comment: And what is your feeling about a **LEFT JOIN IS NULL** approach?

Comment: Yes, @Sergej Popov, this should work fine, but the performance might be an issue.

Comment: @astander, thanks I will consider this for future, but for my level its much easier to understand this. and performance is not a major issue for my current task.

Comment: Glad you got the answer you were looking for. X-)

Comment: @Mark Byers, nice article, but in the summary it does have a **However statement**. And what would be the performance on larger tables?

Comment: @astander: The article says that for non NULL columns, the same query plan is used for all three queries. I guess that  is true regardless of how large the tables are.

Answer (score 2):

Using NOT IN subselects can be a harder performance hit than LEFT-JOIN and expecting NULL

```
SELECT NAME
   FROM People
      LEFT JOIN Assigns
         on People.PID = Assigns.PID
   where
      Assigns.PID IS NULL
```

By using the LEFT-JOIN approach, the People table is going through ONCE with a join to the second based on index find.  It doesn't actually query the entire second "Assigns" file for all possibilities to then join against (and not necessarily take advantage of an index).  The left-join utilizes the index directly and either finds a record or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, the PID will be NULL thus indicating the person is NOT found in the assigns table.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle chose the same execution plan for the NOT IN solution and LEFT JOIN solution